# Where are quadratic probing, double hashing, and cuckoo hashing actually used?

Tags: data-structures, hash, quadratic-probing

Where are quadratic probing, double hashing, and cuckoo hashing actually used?

From what I can tell Java HashMap uses Separate Chaining, and the hash table underlying C++ unordered_map uses linear probing. Are there any commonly used languages / libraries / applications that make use of the more advanced hashing techniques like quadratic probing, double hashing, and cuckoo hashing (among others)?

Comment: For Cuckoo Hashing, see Facebook's [RockDB](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/189f0c27aaecdf17ae7fc1f826a423a28b77984f/docs/_posts/2014-09-12-cuckoo.markdown), for Quadratic Probing see [Go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0a820007e70fdd038950f28254c6269cd9588c02/src/runtime/iface.go#L97).